# Router power switch with bluetooth hands-free

Tags: switches, bluetooth

I want to make a bluetooth switch for my wireless router so I can restart it via my phone.

I have an old bluetooth hands-free so I'm wondering if it could be used as a power switch. I'm planing to connect it to the router's power and use a transistor to shutdown the router, the problem is that I don't know if I can use audio to control the transistor (maybe with a diode and capacitor?)

The idea is to connect the phone to the bluetooth and play an audio file (probably a high pitch tone) so the audio triggers the transistor and shuts off the router, then I'll stop playing the file and the power should come back to the router.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are no answers yet so let me tell you what I found out.

The voltage from the bluetooth thingy is really low so a simple transistor won't work, instead you can use an opamp or a comparator to increase the audio voltage. I'm using a comparator.

After raising the voltage I'm planing to rectify (bridge and caps) the audio signal as good as I can (doesn't matter too much to me if it's not perfect), then the rectified voltage will activate a PNP transistor that will shutdown the router for a couple seconds as long as the audio file is played.